# Shopware6 : Which event to subscribe when an order is paid?

Tags: php, symfony, events, event-handling, shopware

I would like to know which **event** should I use if I want to trigger a function when an order is **PAID** after its creation by the cusstomer.

I have already tried with this one : ***state_enter.order_transaction.state.paid   => 'onOrderCheckout'***.

Unfortunately, it gave an error :"
**Warning**: Use of undefined constant state_enter - assumed 'state_enter' (this will throw an Error in
a future version of PHP)*".

Here is my subscriber :

```
namespace Emakers\TransmissionPlugin\Subscriber;

use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Event\EntityLoadedEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\ExceptionEvent;
use Shopware\Core\Checkout\Order\OrderEntity;
use Shopware\Core\Checkout\Order\OrderEvents;
use Shopware\Core\System\StateMachine\Event;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\Event\EventData\EntityType;
use Shopware\Core\System\SystemConfig\SystemConfigService;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Search\Criteria;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Search\Filter\EqualsFilter;
use Emakers\TransmissionPlugin\Services\ShopwareConnectService;


class OrderSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    /**
     * @ContainerInterface $container
     */
    private $container;


     /**
     * @var datetime
     */
     private $now;


     public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container) {
                $this->container = $container;
                $this->now = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
     }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents(): array
    {
        return [
                'state_enter.order_transaction.state.paid'   => 'onOrderCheckout',
        ];
    }
        public function orOrderCheckout($event)
        {
                var_dump($event);
                die('here we are');
        }
}
```

Comment: add quotes around the name, it's already the right one: 'state_enter.order_transaction.state.paid' (it's not a PHP constant but a simple string in this case)

Comment: @Susi I put the quotes but unfortunately it does not triggered the function onOrderCheckout() when I made an order and paid it directly.

I updated my post to add my subscriber's content, it could maybe help to know what is wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use the StateMachineTransitionEvent for this. Tested with Shopware 6.2.

```
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Your\Namespace;

use Shopware\Core\Checkout\Order\Aggregate\OrderTransaction\OrderTransactionDefinition;
use Shopware\Core\Checkout\Order\Aggregate\OrderTransaction\OrderTransactionStates;
use Shopware\Core\Checkout\Order\OrderEntity;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\Context;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\EntityRepositoryInterface;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Search\Criteria;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Search\Filter\EqualsFilter;
use Shopware\Core\System\StateMachine\Event\StateMachineTransitionEvent;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;

class OrderStateSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface {

    /**
     * @var EntityRepositoryInterface
     */
    private $stateMachineStateRepository;

    /**
     * @var EntityRepositoryInterface
     */
    private $orderRepository;

    public function __construct(EntityRepositoryInterface $stateMachineStateRepository, EntityRepositoryInterface $orderRepository)
    {
        $this->stateMachineStateRepository = $stateMachineStateRepository;
        $this->orderRepository = $orderRepository;
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents(): array
    {
        return [
            StateMachineTransitionEvent::class => 'onStateTransition'
        ];
    }

    public function onStateTransition(StateMachineTransitionEvent $event) {
        // Since you are only interested in order transitions
        if ($event->getEntityName() !== OrderTransactionDefinition::ENTITY_NAME) {
            return;
        }

        $orderTransactionsStatePaidId = $this->getOrderTransactionsStatePaidId($event->getContext());
        if ($orderTransactionsStatePaidId === null) {
            return;
        }

        // Check if it was transitioned to paid
        if ($event->getToPlace()->getId() !== $orderTransactionsStatePaidId) {
            return;
        }

        // Transaction was changed to paid do your thing
        $order = $this->getOrder($event->getEntityId(), $event->getContext());
    }

    private function getOrderTransactionsStatePaidId(Context $context): ?string {
        $criteria = new Criteria();
        // Add filter for OrderTransactionStateMachine
        $criteria->addFilter(
            new EqualsFilter('stateMachine.technicalName', \sprintf('%s.state', OrderTransactionDefinition::ENTITY_NAME)),
            new EqualsFilter('technicalName', OrderTransactionStates::STATE_PAID)
        );

        return $this->stateMachineStateRepository->searchIds($criteria, $context)->firstId();
    }
    
    private function getOrder(string $orderTransactionId, Context $context): ?OrderEntity
    {
        $criteria = new Criteria();
        $criteria->addFilter(
            new EqualsFilter('transactions.id', $orderTransactionId)
        );
        
        return $this->orderRepository->search($criteria, $context)->first();
    }
}
```

In your services xml add something like the following. Of course you need to adjust the FQCN (FullyQualifiedClassName).

```
<service id="Your\Namespace\OrderStateSubscriber">
    <argument type="service" id="state_machine_state.repository"/>
    <argument type="service" id="order.repository"/>
    <tag name="kernel.event_subscriber"/>
</service>
```

Comment: @UmarZahid I added an example services.xml entry.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I found it just after asking you :') 
Last question : I need to get the paid order's informations but when dumping the $event. I didn't have any orderId or something else. 
Is it possible to get them in this case? 
If I just have the orderId, I am happy

Comment: In the event you have the property entityId. This is a OrderTransactionId and with this you can get the Order since they have a direct Association.

Comment: Sorry I could not test right now, I have to wait the colleague to make payments for tests. 

But will this be something like ?: 


`$entityId = $event->getEntityId();

/* @var EntityRepositoryInterface $orderRepository */
 $orderRepository = $this->container->get('order.repository');

$orderInfo = $orderRepository->searchIds( (new Criteria())->addFilter(new EqualsFilter('orderTransactionId', $entityId)),
 \Shopware\Core\Framework\Context::createDefaultContext() )->getIds()[0];`

Comment: I adjusted my Answer so it gets you the order.

Comment: Hi, I try to use it, but I got this error:
Field "technicalName" in entity "order" was not found.
return $this->orderRepository->searchIds($criteria, $context)->firstId();

It looks like the $context passed here is somehow wrong:
`$orderTransactionsStatePaidId = $this->getOrderTransactionsStatePaidId($event->getContext());`
How to solve it?